# In Apex Oracle, is it possible to export a table so that someone else can import and use it for queries?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code

Doing a group project with a few people and we are make the tables separately, is there a way to export a table so that someone else can import it and run queries with it?

someone tried sending me in text form the SQl but it cause way too many errors and the formatting is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we use **Data Pump** export and import utilities to do that. Read about them in documentation.

---

As of Apex itself, go to

1. Object Browser in SQL Workshop
2. select table you want to export
3. go to **DDL** tab so that you could share CREATE TABLE statement
4. go to **Data** tab and choose ...
5. ... **Download** option, which will create an Excel file

Send everything to your friends. They should create a table using DDL script and import data using the

6. **Load data** option

[image]